# How to log Shiro output?

Tags: java, log4j, shiro

Trying to figure out why I cannot see log messages from shiro in the log file described in log4j.properties. All the log messages shown in the code below are recorded in the log file, but I don't see anything from shiro. Not sure what I should see. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Details:

- Using log4j-1.2.17 for logging application log messages.
- Using shiro-1.2.6 for logging in users.
- Using slf4j-log4j12-1.7.9 for shiro to talk to log4j.
- Using java 8.

Please see below details on:

- content of log4j.properties
- included libraries
- code used for shiro login

**log4j.properties**:

```
# Do not inherit appenders from the root logger.
log4j.additivity.default=false

# Set root logger level and attach zero or more appenders.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Set up the file appender.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Name=Logger
log4j.appender.file.File=/path-to-log-file/App.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=25
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6p%d{DATE} - %C{1}.%M:%L - %m%n

# Default Shiro logging
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.io=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.web.servlet=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext=TRACE
```

**List of the libraries in the build path:**

[image: Libraries included in the build path]

**Code that calls shiro to login the users:**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.IncorrectCredentialsException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.LockedAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.RandomNumberGenerator;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.SecureRandomNumberGenerator;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.util.Factory;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

...

Subject newUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
// The username and password authentication token. Set rememberMe to false
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password.toCharArray(), false);
// Retrieve the login principal
String loginPrincipal = (String) token.getPrincipal();

logger.info("*** SERVER: Before SHIRO login.");
logger.info("*** SERVER: loginBean.getUser: " + loginBean.getUserId());
logger.info("*** SERVER: newUser.getSession(): " + newUser.getSession().getId());

// Use the security manager to log in
//It calls UniquePrincipalSecurityManager, which extends DefaultWebSecurityManager
SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager().login(newUser, token);

logger.info("*** SERVER: After SHIRO login.");
logger.info("*** SERVER: newUser.getSession(): " + newUser.getSession().getId());
logger.info("*** SERVER: Logged-In Users (after login event): " + getLoggedInUsers().toString());

...

public class UniquePrincipalSecurityManager extends DefaultWebSecurityManager {

    private static Logger logger = ServerLogging.getServerLogger();

    /**
     * Validates that the user can log into the session and calls Shiro for Login.
     * 
     * @return The subject. Null if not authenticated.
     */
    @Override
    public Subject login(Subject subject, AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Retrieve the login principal
        String loginPrincipal = (String) token.getPrincipal();

        // The final Subject to return
        Subject returnedSubject = null;

        try {
            // Ensure the session is available and that the user can log in
            validateCanLogIntoSession(subject, loginPrincipal);

            logger.info("*** SERVER: Passed validateCanLogIntoSession");

            // Call Shiro for login
            returnedSubject = super.login(subject, token);

            if (returnedSubject != null) {
                logger.info("*** SERVER: loginPrincipal: " + loginPrincipal);
                logger.info("*** SERVER: returnedSubject.getPrincipal(): "
                    + returnedSubject.getPrincipal().toString());
                logger.info("*** SERVER: returnedSubject.getSession(): "
                    + returnedSubject.getSession().getId());
                logger.info("*** SERVER: returnedSubject.isAuthenticated(): "
                    + returnedSubject.isAuthenticated());

            } else {
                logger.info("*** SERVER: Login Failed: " + loginPrincipal);
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            logger.info("*** SERVER: Login Failed: " + loginPrincipal);

            // Something went wrong with the authentication, let the caller deal with it.
            throw ex;
        }
        return returnedSubject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shiro uses SLF4J, this means that Shiro doesn't actually log anything directly, or control how logs are configured for your application. This is one of the most popular Java Logging frameworks out there so I'd recommend taking some time to read about it.

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

The TL;DR is that libraries and frameworks depend on `slf4j-api` and your application provides an actual logging implementation, for example `slf4j-log4j12`.  All the actual logging configuration is done through log4j.

One thing that sticks out is that you are mixing and matching SLF4J versions, which you should not do (and is probably part of the problem you are seeing).

Another thing to point out, and you probably already noticed this, but it is VERY difficult to manage dependencies manually (the old checking in jar files approach), Tools like Maven and Gradle simplify these problems, or if you are using Ant, you could use [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/).