# How to get an application, which is running on a WebLogic server, write Shiro messages to a log file on the server?

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, shiro

**Goal: Have an application, which is running on a WebLogic server, write Shiro messages to a log file on the server**

1. Started on the local machine: Created a small web app that printed org.apache.shiro log messages locally to a log file, together with messages from org.apache.log4j and other libraries like org.apache.commons and net.sf.ehcache. The last two mentioned libraries are triggered by a setting in shiro.ini where I am setting the EhCacheManager as cacheManager, in the [main] section.
2. Moved to WebLogic Sever: Changed the path to the log file to reflect the server's files system structure. Deployed the same application to the WebLogic server. I do see the org.apache.log4j messages written to the log file, but I cannot see the org.apache.shiro messages anymore, nor org.apache.commons, nor net.sf.ehcache. I can see only the log4j messages.

**Debugging Details**

To verify that it's not WebLogic blocking Shiro messages that are debug or trace, I added to the MyServlet.java some log4j debug and trace messages. Those messages are printed out to the log file when deployed to WebLogic server.

```
        log.debug("Debug - Accessing shiro.ini");
...
        log.trace("Trace - Accessing shiro.ini");
```

**Goal**

I need to figure out what causes log messages from other libraries other than log4j, not to be printed to the log files when the application is deployed to WebLogic.

**Desired behavior**

Would like to have the application running on WebLogic, write the Shiro
messages to the log file, just like on the local machine.

Is there a setting in WebLogic that I need to be aware of? Or is it a connector that I need to use. ANY suggestion would help. Thanks!

**Relevant content**

- included libraries
- application files
- output to the log on Server - a lot of content was removed due to limitation on space. Kept some messages to show alternation of output from three different libraries.
- output to the log locally

---

**Included Libraries**

---

- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/shiro-all-1.2.6.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
- /MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar

---

**/MyFirstDynamicProject/src/com/javacodegeeks/MyServlet.java**

---

```
package com.javacodegeeks;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.IncorrectCredentialsException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.LockedAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.session.Session;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.util.Factory;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;

@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final transient Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyServlet.class);

    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/loginView.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Shut down previouse instances of the cache manager
        CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
        if (cm != null) {
            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("Shutting down previous instances of cachemanager.");
            cm.shutdown();
        }

        log.info("");
        log.info("");
        log.info("");
        log.info("Accessing shiro.ini");
        log.debug("");
        log.debug("");
        log.debug("");
        log.debug("Debug - Accessing shiro.ini");
        log.trace("");
        log.trace("");
        log.trace("");
        log.trace("Trace - Accessing shiro.ini");
        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");

        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if (currentUser != null) {

            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("Getting session.");
            Session session = currentUser.getSession();
            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("");
            log.info("Session ID: " + session.getId());

            if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
                String username = "lonestarr";
                String password = "vespa";
                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);

                try {
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("User Logging in.");
                    currentUser.login(token);

                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() + "] logged in successfully.");

                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("");
                    log.info("User Logging out.");
                    currentUser.logout();

                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext()
                        .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/logoutView.jsp");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                    log.info("Username wasn't in the system");
                } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
                    log.info("Password didn't match");
                } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                    log.info("Account for that username is locked");
                } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                    log.info("AuthenticationException: " + ae.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**/MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/loginView.jsp**

---

```
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Login Page</h3>

<p style="color: red;">${errorString}</p>

<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirectId" value="${param.redirectId}" />
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan ="2">
                <input type="submit" value= "User Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**/MyFirstDynamicProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/logoutView.jsp**

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Logout</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Logout Page</h3>

<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>The user was logged out.</td>           
    </tr>   
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**/MyFirstDynamicProject/src/shiro.ini**

---

```
[main]
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

[users]
root = secret, admin
guest = guest, guest
presidentskroob = 12345, president
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed, darklord, schwartz
lonestarr = vespa, goodguy, schwartz

[roles]
admin = *
schwartz = lightsaber:*
goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5
```

---

**/MyFirstDynamicProject/src/log4j.properties**

---

```
# Do not inherit appenders from the root logger.
log4j.additivity.default=false

# Set root logger level and attach zero or more appenders.
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file, A1

# console appender config
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6p%d{DATE} - %C{10}.%M:%L - %m%n

# Set up the file appender.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Name=MyServlet
log4j.appender.file.File=<path-to-log-locally>\\Alina.log
#log4j.appender.file.File=<path-to-log-on-WebLogicServer>/Alina.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=25
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
```

---

**build.xml**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="MyFirstDynamicProject" default="build" basedir=".">

    <!-- SETTINGS -->

    <!-- GLOBAL PROPERTIES -->
    <property name="war.file" value="MyFirstDynamicProject.war" />
    <property name="base.module" value="com.javaccodegeeks.MyServlet" />

    <!-- PRODUCTION PROPERTIES -->
    <property name="prod.warDir" value="war" />

    <!-- DEVELOPMENT PROPERTIES -->
    <property name="dev.port" value="8889" />
    <property name="dev.logLevel" value="INFO" />
    <property name="dev.startPage" value="WEB-INF/views/loginView.jsp" />
    <property name="dev.warDir" value="war" />


    <path id="project.class.path">
        <pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>


    <!-- LIBS -->
    <target name="libs" description="Copy libs to WEB-INF/lib">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
            <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </copy>
    </target>
    
    <!-- MANIFEST -->
    <target name="manifest" description="Copy manifest to META-INF">
        <mkdir dir="war/META-INF" />
        <copy todir="war/META-INF">
            <fileset dir="WebContent/META-INF" includes="**/*" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- RESOURCES -->
    <target name="resources" description="Copy web resources to various directories">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/views" />
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/views">
            <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/views" includes="**/*" />
        </copy>     
    </target>

    <!-- JAVA COMPILE -->
    <target name="javac" depends="libs,resources,manifest"
        description="Compile java source to bytecode">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
            includeantruntime="false" destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes" source="1.7"
            target="1.7" nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
        </javac>
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java" />
                <exclude name="META-INF/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>   


    <!-- BUILD OPTIONS -->
    <target name="build" depends="javac" description="Build this project">
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="clean,build" description="Create a war file">
        <mkdir dir="war" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <zip destfile="dist/${war.file}" basedir="war" />
        <delete dir="gwt-unitCache" failonerror="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans this project">
        <delete dir="war" failonerror="false" />
        <delete dir="dist" failonerror="false" />
    </target>
</project>
```

---

**Log output to Alina.log from WebLogic deployment**

---

```
...
t:964 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:55 - Shutting down previous instances of cachemanager.
...
t:968 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:62 - Accessing shiro.ini
...
t:969 DEBUG com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:66 - Debug - Accessing shiro.ini
... 
t:970 TRACE com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:70 - Trace - Accessing shiro.ini
...
t:359 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:82 - Getting session.
...
t:385 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:87 - Session ID: cde2e30c-058b-4e3b-a500-f9222363f84d
...
t:386 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:98 - User Logging in.
... 
t:391 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:104 - User [lonestarr] logged in successfully.
... 
t:392 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:109 - User Logging out.
```

---

**Log output to Alina.log when running the app locally**

---

```
t:968 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory:136 - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/P:/Users/freyada/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyFirstDynamicProject/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
t:980 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory:98 - Configuring ehcache from URL: jar:file:/P:/Users/freyada/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyFirstDynamicProject/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
...
<removed content>
...
t:673 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper:100 - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
t:710 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:52 - 
...
<removed content>
...
t:727 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:61 - 
t:727 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:62 - Accessing shiro.ini
...
<removed content>
...
t:730 DEBUG com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:66 - Debug - Accessing shiro.ini
...
<removed content>
...
t:743 TRACE com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:70 - Trace - Accessing shiro.ini
t:788 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.io.ResourceUtils:159 - Opening resource from class path [shiro.ini]
t:842 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.config.Ini:401 - Parsing [main]
t:850 TRACE org.apache.shiro.config.Ini:604 - Discovered key/value pair: sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
...
<removed content>
...
t:884 TRACE org.apache.shiro.config.Ini:604 - Discovered key/value pair: schwartz = lightsaber:*
t:888 TRACE org.apache.shiro.config.Ini:604 - Discovered key/value pair: goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5
t:035 DEBUG org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter:353 - Setting default value: false
...
<removed content>
...
t:191 DEBUG org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ArrayConverter:140 - Converting 'java.net.URL[]' value '[Ljava.net.URL;@3af593b1' to type 'java.net.URL[]'
t:197 DEBUG org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ArrayConverter:162 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.net.URL[]
t:240 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils:284 - Unable to load clazz named [org.apache.commons.configuration2.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator] from class loader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: MyFirstDynamicProject
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@52cc8049
]
t:241 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils:155 - Unable to load class named [org.apache.commons.configuration2.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator] from the thread context ClassLoader.  Trying the current ClassLoader...
t:242 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils:284 - Unable to load clazz named [org.apache.commons.configuration2.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator] from class loader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: MyFirstDynamicProject
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@52cc8049
]
t:243 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils:163 - Unable to load class named [org.apache.commons.configuration2.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator] from the current ClassLoader.  Trying the system/application ClassLoader...
t:244 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils:284 - Unable to load clazz named [org.apache.commons.configuration2.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator] from class loader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
t:491 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport:149 - Creating instance from Ini [sections=main,users,roles]
t:812 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder:424 - Encountered object reference '$sessionDAO'.  Looking up object with id 'sessionDAO'
t:813 TRACE org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder:675 - Applying property [sessionManager.sessionDAO] value [org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO@19b30d06] on object of type [org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager]
t:814 TRACE org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils:888 -   setProperty(org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager@f27f1ee, sessionManager.sessionDAO, org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO@19b30d06)
...
<removed content>
...
t:823 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager:205 - cacheManager property not set.  Constructing CacheManager instance... 
t:824 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.io.ResourceUtils:159 - Opening resource from class path [org/apache/shiro/cache/ehcache/ehcache.xml]
t:828 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory:150 - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
t:835 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.DiskStoreConfiguration:141 - Disk Store Path: P:\Users\freyada\AppData\Local\Temp\/shiro-ehcache
t:841 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil:87 - propertiesString is null.
t:844 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper:189 - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
...
<removed content>
...
t:463 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper:334 - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm-0-accounts'.
t:463 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper:364 - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm-0-accounts'.
t:464 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager:214 - instantiated Ehcache CacheManager instance.
t:465 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager:218 - implicit cacheManager created successfully.
t:466 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder:424 - Encountered object reference '$cacheManager'.  Looking up object with id 'cacheManager'
t:466 TRACE org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder:675 - Applying property [cacheManager] value [org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager@6604c0ae] on object of type [org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager]
...
<removed content>
...
apache.shiro.mgt.CachingSecurityManager.setCacheManager(org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager) with value org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager@6604c0ae (class org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager)
t:469 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm:179 - Discovered the [roles] section.  Processing...
t:478 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm:185 - Discovered the [users] section.  Processing...
...
<removed content>
...
t:539 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = true; session has id = false
t:540 TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext:169 - Bound value of type [org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject] for key [org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext_SUBJECT_KEY] to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-3]
t:540 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:79 - 
...
<removed content>
...
t:541 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:82 - Getting session.
t:541 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = true; session is null = true; session has id = false
t:541 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:338 - Starting session for host null
t:547 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager:213 - No sessionValidationScheduler set.  Attempting to create default instance.
...
<removed content>
...
t:573 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:580 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:75 - Element for [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae] is null.
t:594 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:434 - put added 0 on heap
t:609 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:610 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:434 - put added 0 on heap
...
<removed content>
...
t:627 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:86 - 
t:628 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:87 - Session ID: c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae
...
<removed content>
...
t:629 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:97 - 
t:630 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:98 - User Logging in.
t:630 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
...
<removed content>
...
t:631 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:632 TRACE org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator:194 - Authentication attempt received for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - lonestarr, rememberMe=false]
t:633 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm:572 - Looked up AuthenticationInfo [lonestarr] from doGetAuthenticationInfo
t:633 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm:510 - AuthenticationInfo caching is disabled for info [lonestarr].  Submitted token: [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - lonestarr, rememberMe=false].
t:633 t:DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:764 - fault removed 0 from heap
t:635 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.SimpleCredentialsMatcher:96 - Performing credentials equality check for tokenCredentials of type [[C and accountCredentials of type [java.lang.String]
t:636 t:DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:777 - fault added 0 on disk
t:636 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.SimpleCredentialsMatcher:102 - Both credentials arguments can be easily converted to byte arrays.  Performing array equals comparison
...
<removed content>
...
t:637 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator:233 - Authentication successful for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - lonestarr, rememberMe=false].  Returned account [lonestarr]
t:638 TRACE org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager:417 - Context already contains a SecurityManager instance.  Returning.
...
<removed content>
...
t:640 TRACE org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager:116 - Attempting to retrieve session with key org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionKey@a68f47a
t:641 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:642 t:DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:764 - fault removed 0 from heap
...
<removed content>
...
t:642 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
t:643 TRACE org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager:116 - Attempting to retrieve session with key org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionKey@a68f47a
t:644 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
...
<removed content>
...
t:648 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:96 - Putting object in cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:649 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:649 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:434 - put added 0 on heap
...
<removed content>
...
t:670 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:670 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:434 - put added 0 on heap
t:671 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:462 - put updated, deleted 0 on heap
t:672 TRACE org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager:222 - This org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager instance does not have a [org.apache.shiro.mgt.RememberMeManager] instance configured.  RememberMe services will not be performed for account [lonestarr].
t:672 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
t:672 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:101 - 
...
<removed content>
...
t:673 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
t:674 TRACE org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager:116 - Attempting to retrieve session with key org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionKey@a68f47a
t:674 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:675 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:104 - User [lonestarr] logged in successfully.
...
<removed content>
...
t:677 INFO  com.javacodegeeks.MyServlet:109 - User Logging out.
t:678 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
...
<removed content>
...
t:681 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:681 t:DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:764 - fault removed 0 from heap
t:681 DEBUG org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager:559 - Logging out subject with primary principal lonestarr
t:682 t:DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:777 - fault added 0 on disk
...
<removed content>
...
t:683 TRACE org.apache.shiro.realm.CachingRealm:171 - Cleared cache entries for account with principals [lonestarr]
...
<removed content>
...
t:687 TRACE org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache:67 - Getting object from cache [shiro-activeSessionCache] for key [c9e56b20-d05a-4aa9-b54c-b7cfc23d76ae]
t:687 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:434 - put added 0 on heap
...
<removed content>
...
t:693 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:466 - put updated, deleted 0 on disk
t:702 TRACE org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject:321 - attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true
...
<removed content>
...
t:715 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment:681 - remove deleted nothing
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log Shiro output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086214/how-to-log-shiro-output)